# Creating new CSS class- and ID-names, making sure nothing breaks

Tags: html, css, naming-conventions

I am working on some large web projects at work, and a lot of HTML ID's and Classnames are being used.

When I create something new in one of those huge projects, naming new ID's and classes can be frustrating, because I always end up with something like `#subprojectname_title` , `.subprojectname_editor` to make sure that I don't overwrite any classes and ID's that have previously been written for the "parent" project, and to make sure I dont inherit the previously written styles.

I always have to write `subprojectname` whenever I create a new class or id for that subproject, and thats quite annoying.

I'm looking for suggestions on how I can make my selectors shorter, without having to reset the style to make sure I dont inherit from the previous selector, and without messing with the previously written styles (overwriting them, changing their names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a simple solution for this in my projects.

I use "unique" names for globally effective styles and "common" names for local scope.

i.e. My site.css uses names such as "defaultList" or "defaultWhiteButton", where as my pageX.css uses "list" and "button".

I never make use of IDs for my selectors, since IDs are used (in my purposes) for all programmatic behavior and not cosmetic.

I make use of classes only in my CSS.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great answer, but I'm afraid that the site-wide styles are already "commonly named" - such as ".ok", ".error", ".title"...

Comment: why should you local scope need to have specific names? aren't they only loaded for those specific pages? i.e. my Transactions.aspx uses the name class names as Deals.aspx, but each calls a different CSS (Transactions.css and Deals.css). Same names, but they behave slightly differently.

Comment: Stuff like .title, .ok, etc are used globally across all pages

Comment: - and, sometimes my subprojects are being used globally as well.

Comment: then might is suggest cleaning stuff up instead of making it worse with using explicit naming in only some places?

Comment: Tell that to my boss - he wrote the parent project. I'm just an apprentince.

Comment: Getting a software developer job around here is tough, so I'd rather not. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .subproject_thingie1 and .subproject_thingie2 everywhere I usually go for adding a root class or id to differentiate between projects/pages.

That way you can have global styling maintained on all pages on the same class names while being able to add specific rules for specific pages.

But as always, the best solution depends on how well the existing project is written.

Comment: I considered that, but then I'd have to get rid of all the styling I didn't need, which means writing unnecesary CSS rules.

Comment: If unavoidable I rather have more styling rules than illogical non maintainable naming in html. Of course I have no idea how bad this would be for you. Maybe you're at the point to consider not to include the original style sheets.

Comment: The original stylesheets are included on the master page